# Javascript document.location new window

Tags: javascript, pinterest, new-window

I am making a custom Pinterest Pin It button with [Simple Icons](http://simpleicons.org), and I'm using the link that Pinterest Widget Builder gave me. On the default Pin It buttons, it opens this link in a completely new **window**. I have looked at plenty of SO questions, but all of these open it in a new **tab**.

I need this link to be opened in a new **window**, not **tab**.

HTML:

```
<div class="pinit" onclick='window.open("http://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2FHowl%2FHome.html&media=http%3A%2F%2Fi.imgur.com%2FToZz7PB.png&description=Howl%3A%20Share%20Your%20Life")'><img src="http://raw.github.com/danleech/simpleicons/master/icons/pinterest/pinterest-64.png"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.pinit {
  background: #CB2027;
  width: 65px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.pinit:hover {
  background: #e41f11
}
```

JavaScript:

For the JS, I used the Pinterest link: `<script type="text/javascript" async src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this one

```
<div class="pinit" onclick='window.open("http://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2FHowl%2FHome.html&media=http%3A%2F%2Fi.imgur.com%2FToZz7PB.png&description=Howl%3A%20Share%20Your%20Life","Pin It","width=300,height=300,top=0,left100")'>
```

provide name and properties to your new window.

```
,"Pin It","width=300,height=300,top=0,left100"
```

Comment: I don't think the sizing works. The height doesn't look 300px. Do you need the px in it?

Comment: its height in 'px' you can try other number aside from 300 like width=600,height=500

Comment: I have been resizing it, and it still looks thin and tall.

Comment: what size are you using?

Comment: never mind, i found the problem. i switched the width with the height so the height was 700 and width was 300. thats why it was tall and thin